# Drag to change image slide with jquery like in iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, drag, swipe-gesture

Am using supersized jquery plugin for my site. It comes with button for next and previous slides. I want to implement drag to change feature in it. If some one click and move mouse to right it should act as the next slide button.

But how can i do it with jquery? How can i know when user click n drag to left/right

> http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Comment: So what's keeping you from doing it?

Comment: I have updated question. I dont know how to detect swipe like movement in jquery and how to detect in which direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery recognizes `mouseUp`, `mouseDown` and `mouseMove` as events.

You would have to capture the mouseposition on `mouseDown`, update the position while it's moving and compare that to your initially captured position. 
While this is highly theoretical, check here [Recreate Iphone Swipe effect using jQuery](http://nooshu.com/recreate-iphone-swipe-effect-using-jquery)
for a live example.